# Convert SQL NOT IN query to LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have two tables: User and UserRole.

I have the following SQL query to get all users who are NOT IN a certain role:

```
SELECT * FROM User
WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserRole WHERE RoleID = 32)
```

Assuming I have a User entity and a UserRole entity in my **EF 5** model, how do I write a **LINQ to Entities** query to get the same results as the SQL query above?

Comment: Do you have navigation properties in your models ?

Comment: @ Raphaël Althaus - yes navigation properties are defined... "UserRolesAssigned" is the name of the navigation property from User entity to UserRole entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use something like:

```
repo.Users.Where(x => x.UserRoles.Where(y => y.RoleID == 32).Count() == 0)
```

or, according remarks :

```
repo.Users.Where(x => !x.UserRoles.Any(y => y.RoleID == 32))
```

or

```
repo.Users.Where(x => x.UserRoles.Count(y => y.RoleID == 32) == 0)
```

or

```
...
```

Comment: just preference, but you can change the `.Count() == 0` to be `!x.Roles.Any(y => y.Id == 32)`

Comment: I tested and confirmed all three examples return the expected results. I chose to use the one in the middle -- repo.Users.Where(x => !x.UserRoles.Any(y => y.RoleID == 32)) -- for the sake of brevity.